# Should I save my blood?

Tags: blood-brothers

I have a large amount of blood meals (100+). When questing should I use them at every single opportunity, or should i save them for better areas?

I am currently on the first underground level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a great reason to save them at that point. Blood meals max out at 999 currently.  They could be used to increase your "collections", but their main value is in bringing up skill levels for familiars by doing the 'blood brothers' vaporizing thing. 
At 100+, I would try only for long-shot UC chances, as those net you 45 skill points, unless you really need the common variety for boosting.  Given the limit of familiars you can hold, the common ones start to become more trouble than they're worth.  You'll still want to keep some blood meals for events, as they might be useful for catching the tournament type of familiars.

Comment: A good answer, but its worth nothing that the maximum is currently 999. This was increased from (I think) 255 a few weeks ago

Comment: Regarding catching tournament familiars with blood meals, I've used about 10 so far in the few events I've done on familiars, and it failed each time. I feel the Mobage just wants us to use heartbloods, which cost money (or can be traded for, I guess, but that's not what Mobage wants).

Comment: @David As far as I can tell, you've got a chance every time, and the percentage gets lower as the rarity increases.  I've gotten C, UC, EP all with the blood meals (including the level bosses).  Someone has probably gotten a better idea, but C seems about 66-75%, UC captures maybe 10%, and rares are perhaps 5%.

Answer (score 0):

In Tower Events, extra event points are earned for "capture" of encountered enemies. Hence by saving all your blood meals till Tower Event you'll have more chances to earn event points. Other than that they are pretty useless.